# Blog post: Question of the Month for August 2011

Tags: discussion, blog

Let's try doing a "question of the month" post for the [Bicycles.SE site blog](http://bicycles.blogoverflow.com/). There could be more than one question featured, but let's keep this to questions submitted during the month of August.

freiheit has already [suggested a few questions in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1838333#1838333).

It'd be great if people could post questions here that they particularly like, one question per answer so we can vote them up and down. Importantly, *why* do you like the question? I'll make this community wiki, so feel free to edit anything here, including this question.

(Alternatively, if you think this post(s)-of-the-month thing is a terrible idea, tell everyone why.)

Edit: Importantly, **will anyone here volunteer to write this up?**

Comment: Anybody can propose any question they want, but I've been looking at [highly voted](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes) and [questions with most views, answers and votes](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/?tab=month).

Answer (score 3):

I think we could editorialize a few questions that touch on something to make a coherent article. Rather than 'question of the month' it could be 'hot topic of the month'.

For instance there have been a few questions on what chain or belt to use for single speed/geared hubs. We could roll these into one article that intelligently discusses history (Sturmey Archer, flip-flop hubs), standards (1/8", dropout type, spindle length), technical bits such as tensioners and chain line and recent developments, e.g. Alfine 11 speed and belt drives.

What connector link is one question. There is also a question on why the chain on an Electra Townie 'has no oil' - the chain is coated to be 'rust proof'. A couple of belt questions materialized and I am sure there was something about Alfine.

Comment: This could be fun, it could even apply to the whole summer. Would you be willing to write up a "hot topic of the summer" post?

Comment: @Neil Fein - I think a collaborative essay could work well - I am willing to give it a go, but I will need you to check for faux pas as my only non-derailleur bike has a 55 year old Sturmey Archer hub and I have one blog post to finish as it is...!

Comment: Sure, let's give it a go. Start the essay here as a CW answer and others can add to it.

Answer (score 1):

## [How to use drop handlebars properly?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/5251/how-to-use-drop-handlebars-properly)

The question is clear, has enough detail but not too much. Practical, answerable, applies to a lot of people. Decent number of votes and views. Answered nicely with a picture and good explanation.